# Display tag pagination error on Spring + Hibernate MVC?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, displaytag

I am doing on an MVC project using spring, hibernate and I have a problem when navigating between pages in displat:table, it just show the first 10 items of the list (pagesize=10). When I navigate to other pages, it displays an url:http://localhost:8080/pinky_spring/clothes.jsp?d-1339940-p=7 and 404 error. Here is my definition for display:table

```
<display:table id="table_clothes" name="clothes" pagesize="10"
                               requestURI = "/clothes.jsp" 
                               keepStatus = "true" 
                               uid = "myTable" 
                               decorator="table_decorate.ClothesDecorate" >
    <display:column property="id" title=""/>
    <display:column title="no">
        <c:out value="${table_clothes_rowNum}"/>
    </display:column>
    <display:column property="name" />
    <display:column property="price" />
    <display:column property="dayUpdate" title="Update" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="pictures" title="Img"/>
    <display:column property="quantities" title="Qty"/>
</display:table>
```

And here is my controller

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("clothes");
    List<Clothes> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        clothes = session.createQuery("from Clothes").list();
        session.getTransaction();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        mv.addObject("clothes", clothes);
    }
    return mv;
}
```

Please help me, I am a newbie in java web!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple, I set requestURI="" and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

The `requestURI` of the display:table tag should point to the controller's URL .

Comment: Can you explain it clearer, you means that I should handle this GET method on controller?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 Correct, the `handleRequest` controller method needs to be executed for each page change since your `ModelAndView` needs to be reconstructed.

Comment: OK, but the parameter is looked like this '?d-1339940-p=6' and the parameter name is different in each jsp page, how can I 'formed' them into one type?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 Your controller is providing the page a full list of objects  so the display tag will use the `d-(encoded table id)-p` parameter to get the sub list of objects for the actual page based on page size.  Essentially, the way you're getting the data, you do not need to be concerned with the parameter.

Comment: Here is the tree view of my app, how can i set the URL to my controller: http://i.imgur.com/oE0bl6d.png

Comment: @iamatsundere181 The `requestURI` needs to point to the URL you navigate to in order to invoke `ClothesController`.

Comment: I had my solution for this, please check it below! May be it will give you guys some solutions for other problems!